# Stretching SKSpriteNodes

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have an `SKSpriteNode` with the `SKTexture` seen below. I set the `centerRect` of my node to what I though would tell it to stretch upwards so the arrow doesn't become distorted. The image is `190x190 px` and I'm setting my `centerRect` as such:

```
CGRectMake(90/190, 90/190, 5/190, 5/190);
```

[image]

From my understand from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH9-SW10), this is saying that each corner is `90x90 px`, and the center rect of the 3x3 grid is `5x5 px`. Which would mean only the center 5x5 pixels are stretched.

But my result is this:

[image]

I have a class called `Obstacle` which is a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` and when it gets initialized,it passes in the `CGRect` above along with the image name to this method:

```
-(void)setTextureNamed:(NSString*)imageName centerRect:(CGRect)rect
{
// set texture for sprite
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed: imageName];

SKTexture* texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage: image];
[self setTexture: texture];

// make stretchable
self.centerRect = rect;

[self setSize: texture.size];
}
```

And in my `SKScene`, when an `Obstacle` is added, this code is called:

```
int bottomHeight, topHeight, topY, bottomY, max;
bottomY = 0;//_floor.size.height/2;
max = self.view.frame.size.height - _floor.size.height/2 - 2*OBSTACLE_PADDING - 2*OBSTACLE_MIN_HEIGHT;
bottomHeight = arc4random() % max + OBSTACLE_MIN_HEIGHT;
topY = bottomHeight + OBSTACLE_PADDING + _floor.size.height;
topHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - topY;

bottomY += bottomHeight/2;
topY += topHeight/2;

Obstacle *bottom = [[Obstacle alloc] initWithHeight: bottomHeight flipped: NO];
bottom.zPosition = 0;
[bottom setPosition: CGPointMake(400, bottomY)];

NSArray* objs = @[bottom, top];

for (Obstacle* o in objs)
{
    o.zPosition = 2;
    [self addChild: o];
    [o runAction: [SKAction
                        moveToX: -100 duration: SPAWN_SPEED*2]
           completion:^{
               [o removeFromParent];
           }];

}
```

Comment: I think that's because of the way you are presenting the SKView to UIViewController's view in viewDidLoad.  But who knows?  We have little information.

Comment: Post more code, instead of describing what you are trying to do

Comment: @AndreyGordeev Sorry, I posed a few more blocks of code that are responsible for creating the objects in question

Answer (score 0):

Set the scale of the SKSpriteNode not the size. **[self setScale:...]**